# Distribute GPU to each job

Tags: python, shell, gpu

Now I have 3 jobs running at the same time in server. And the server has 3 GPUs. So if I don't distribute each GPU to each job, the 3 jobs might compete to use the fastest GPU. It might be a little inefficient if the running time is too long. So what should I do or what should I add to my code so that each job can find a vacant GPU? (I program by python and shell)

Comment: Do you have some code to show ? Are you talking about GPU or CPU ? What lib are you using for python to run on GPU ? What are your GPUs ?

Comment: If you are actually talking about CPUs (they do the normal stuff) and not GPUs (for graphics) then you should have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

Comment: Actually my work involvus many shell and python scripts. And the shell script which specifies GPU device is shown below. I use Anaconda2.0 for python and GPU is Nvidia K20xm.
#!/bin/sh
# theano device, in case you do not want to compute on gpu, change it to cpu
device=gpu

paramfile=$1
source $paramfile

THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,floatX=float32,device=$device,on_unused_input=warn python ${$md_dir}/train_config.py \
    --paramfile $paramfile \
    --modelname $modelname \
  (I deleted unrelated parameters here)